# Can analytic/window functions be used to find a subset of words that begin other words?

Tags: mysql, sql

I’m trying to find a single pass way of traversing an ordered list of words, looking for the shortest previous word that the current word begins with

Essentially in the following list:

```
'APP',3
'APPLE',2
'APPLICATION',7
'BOW',2
'BRA',6
'BRAVE',5
'BRAVERY',3
'CANED',2
'CANES',4
```

I’d like to eliminate APPLE, APPLICATION, BRAVE and BRAVERY but add their numerical scores to the root word that they start with, so APP scores 3+2+7 and BRA scores 6+5+3

```
'APP',12
'BRA',14
'BOW',2
'CANED',2
'CANES',4
```

Though bravery starts with brave and bra, its root word is bra, because bra is shorter than brave

I get the feeling it can be done by creating a column that increments each time the current row word doesn’t start with any previous row word and the current row word is not longer than the previous row word, then use that as a partition.. It’s the “with any previous row word” bit that I’m stuck on- essentially Apple and Application both start with App, but Application doesn’t start with Apple (and bravery does start with brave) so comparing the immediate previous row for being like the current row doesn’t work

I’m not hugely fussed about which DB this is; I’m using MySQL 8’s analytics for this, but it’s more the general technique I’m after as I can just as easily have our sqlserver or oracle do the work

I can already do this using joins, I’m wondering if there’s a way that avoids all use of joining

Comment: Two separate columns, sorry for not making that clear

Answer (score 2):

I realise this doesn't use window/analytic functions, but if the list is ordered this is a pretty easy problem, just maintain the current prefix string until the next word in the list doesn't match it (i.e. `Name NOT LIKE CONCAT(@prefix, '_%')`, and at that point change the prefix to that word. So you can create a list of the words and their prefixes:

```
SELECT Name, Value, @prefix:=IF(Name NOT LIKE CONCAT(@prefix, '_%'), Name, @prefix) AS prefix
FROM table1
JOIN (SELECT @prefix := '~') p;
```

Output:

```
Name            Value   prefix
APP             3       APP
APPLE           2       APP
APPLICATION     7       APP
BOW             2       BOW
BRA             6       BRA
BRAVE           5       BRA
BRAVERY         3       BRA
CANES           4       CANES
CANED           2       CANED
```

That data can then be summed and grouped by prefix:

```
SELECT prefix, SUM(`Value`)
FROM (SELECT Name, Value, @prefix:=IF(Name NOT LIKE CONCAT(@prefix, '_%'), Name, @prefix) AS prefix
      FROM table1
      JOIN (SELECT @prefix := '~') p
      ) t2
GROUP BY prefix
```

Output:

```
prefix  SUM(`Value`)
APP     12
BOW     2
BRA     14
CANED   2
CANES   4
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1857b/2) (Note I took the liberty of sorting `BOW` before `BRA`)

Comment: This is probably the best way to approach this problem in MySQL.

Comment: @gordonlinoff would you approach it similarly in SQLS/Oracle? And am I right in thinking there isn't a way to bully analytics into doing this?

Comment: @nick thanks for this, and pointing out I'd slipped up with the ordering on BOW :)

Comment: @CaiusJard . . . This is one of those unusual situations where variables seem like a really good solution.  If you are interested in a solution in Oracle, then ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative version using cte's. Also include the create an insert so you can cut and paste as a full example.

```
declare @w table(word varchar(20), cnt int)
insert @w values ('APP',3)
,('APPLE',2)
,('APPLICATION',7)
,('BRA',6)
,('BRAVE',5)
,('BRAVERY',3)
,('BOW',2)
,('CANES',4)
,('CANED',2)

;with cte as(
    select w.word, w2.word as baseword, w.cnt
    from @w w
    join @w w2 on w.word like w2.word+'%' 
    and not exists(select * from @w w3 where w.word like w3.word+'%' and len(w3.word)<len(w2.word))
)
select baseword, sum(cnt) as [count] from cte group by baseword
```

Output:

```
baseword    count
APP    12
BOW     2
BRA    14
CANED   2
CANES   4
```